# Fail2Ban для docker nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, fail2ban

Не понимаю где мог недосмотреть, ведь временную зону передаю через docker-compose

```
environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
```

В итоге вот это:

```
fail2ban      | 2021-06-12 13:59:59,169 fail2ban.filter         [1]: WARNING [nginx-http-auth] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation None ~ 1623495599.1693964 +/- 60
fail2ban      | 2021-06-12 13:59:59,169 fail2ban.filter         [1]: WARNING [nginx-http-auth] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: 192.168.176.1 - - [12/Jun/2021:13:59:59 +0300] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 4857 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это не ошибка около TZ - выглядит так как будто fail2ban не распознал формат для времени (т.к. там стоит None ~ 1623495599 +/- 60), это тупо ошибка - он должен кидаться здесь другим варнингом.

Сообщение 404 записано в лог в 13:59:59 MSK ("2021-06-12 13:59:59 +0300" это действительно 1623495599, фильтр fail2ban получил эту попытку тоже в 13:59:59(.169), т.е. тут всё в порядке с временной зоной.
Просто скорее всего определен неправильный формат `datepattern` (потому что совсем без него, fail2ban нашел бы - это вроде стандартный формат) и вероятно "слабый" `failregex` с catch-all's и т.п.

Хоть записывать timestamp после foreign input это "моветон" (лучше переписать формат с timestamp в начале строки), но можно и так:

```
datepattern = \[%%d/%%b/%%Y[ :]?%%H:%%M:%%S(?:\.%%f)?(?: %%z)?\]\s+
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ "[A-Z]+ [^"]*" 40\d+
```

Если datepattern всё же подвинется в начало, его можно и заякорить для надежности (используя `^` как в `failregex`).